# Error :System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to debug the above error. Below is my code.

```
private SqlConnection SQLConn(string name) 
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name].ConnectionString;
    return conn;
}

 protected void rb2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();

    conn = SQLConn("Plastics");
  try
    {
        string selectSQL = "SELECT [Description], [Code], [Change] FROM [plastics]";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, conn);

        conn.Open();

        GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
    catch (SqlException Exception)
    {
        // catch exception
        Response.Write("An error occured");
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }

}
```

I get an error on  GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();

What must I instantiate?

Comment: check `if (GridView1 != null)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response.No error appearing after after I put the if statement, but gridview not show.

Comment: Do you have a GridView named GridView1 in your .aspx file?

Comment: does your 'SqlDataReader' is null?

Comment: may be the connection is null

Comment: What happens when you run your code in a debugger?

Comment: @simon-svensson Yes I have a gridview named GridView1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    string str = "User ID=username;Password=password;Data Source=Test";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from table_name";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd); 
    da.Fill(dt);
    if(dt!=null)
    {
       GridView2.DataSource = dt;
       GridView2.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great job with `using` on the `DataSet` but not the important stuff like `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter`.

Comment: Since this is a disconnected architecture , there is no chance of resources being held up. We might want to consider only freeing up DataSet ...

Comment: Thanks for the code. I still get an the same error on GridView1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: Can you run the query which you have put above in your SQL to see if you get any output first ??? or can you debug and see if there is any data in your Datatable .

Comment: You also try setting AutoGenerateColumns to true